# Holding place for appendChild node in HTML form to not cause the following elements pushed down below

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, user-interface

Appending the child node to the form is pushing the footer down a little to make room for it. How can I hold the place for the child node beforehand so that my footer is not pushed down while the message is fading in place?

**CSS**

```
.containerForm {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

    .containerForm h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .containerForm .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .containerForm label {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .containerForm input, textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .containerForm button {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .containerForm button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }

.success-message {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #4CAF50;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadeIn 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This will be the handling method in JS. Please note currently the method is simulating as if there is a submission process in action.
**JS**

```
document.getElementById("contact-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event)
 {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    var submitButton = document.querySelector("button[type='submit']");
    submitButton.disabled = true;

    // TODO: invoke controller method.

    // Simulating a processing delay
    setTimeout(function () {
        submitButton.disabled = false;

        var successMessage = document.createElement("p");
        successMessage.textContent = "Thank you, your message has been sent.";
        successMessage.classList.add("success-message");

        document.getElementById("contact-form").appendChild(successMessage);

        // Reset the form fields after a delay
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
            successMessage.remove();
        }, 3000);
        
    }, 2000);
});
```

Mark up for the form.
**HTML**

```
<main>  
    <div class="containerForm">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <form id="contact-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>          
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; XYZ. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Does adding [`margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top) to the footer fix what you want?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Nope, it does not. It's only going to push the footer down by a certain margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set height from `0` to `fit-content` (or a hardcoded value) in your fade-in animation

Answer (score 0):

I've got a nice idea, while you can't really preserve space for an element, you can hide it using the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) CSS property, and then show it later.

```js
var successMessage = document.getElementById("successMessage");
successMessage.style.marginTop = "10px;";
successMessage.style.visibility = "hidden";

document.getElementById("contact-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("button[type='submit']");
    submitButton.disabled = true;

    // TODO: invoke controller method.

    // Simulating a processing delay
    setTimeout(function () {
        submitButton.disabled = false;

        var successMessage = document.getElementById("successMessage");
        successMessage.style.visibility = "visible";
        successMessage.textContent = "Thank you, your message has been sent.";
        successMessage.classList.add("success-message");

        document.getElementById("contact-form").appendChild(successMessage);

        // Reset the form fields after a delay
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
            successMessage.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }, 3000);
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.containerForm {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.containerForm h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.containerForm .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.containerForm label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.containerForm input,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.containerForm button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.containerForm button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.success-message {
    color: #4caf50;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadeIn 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="containerForm">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <form id="contact-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <p id="successMessage">Hello, I am hidden!</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; XYZ. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

## <dialog>

Instead of disturbing your HTML layout for a temporary message to the user, display any message to the user with `<dialog>` instead. `<dialog>` is basically a HTMLElement that has special behavior akin to that of a dialog, modal, popup, etc. A small amount of JavaScript is required to open it, see the example below.

### References

[<dialog>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

[HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements)

[HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

[form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content)

### Example

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Register the "submit" event to <form id="contact">
document.forms.contact.onsubmit = simulateSubmit;

function simulateSubmit(event) {
  // Stop normal "submit" event behavior
  event.preventDefault();
  // Collect all form controls of <form> into a HTMLCollection
  const io = this.elements;
  // Reference <dialog> through the <output>
  const popup = io.modal.parentElement;
  
  // Open and close <dialog> at specific times
  setTimeout(() => {
    io.modal.value = `Thank you ${io.user.value}, your message has been sent.`;
    popup.showModal();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.reset();
      popup.close();
    }, 5000);

  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  font: 2.25ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6ex;
  margin-top: 4ex;
  padding: 8px 4px 12px;
  border-bottom: 3px ridge grey;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

main {
  height: max-content;
  margin: 4ex auto;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 16px;
  margin: 2ex auto;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: -8px
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
}

label b {
  display: block;
  width: 6ch;
}

input,
textarea,
button {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

button {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 8ch;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 36ch;
  margin-left: 3ch;
}

footer {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 3px ridge grey;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

small::before {
  content: "\0000a9\00fe0f\0000a0";
}

.top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

dialog {
  width: max-content;
}

output {
  display: block;
  min-height: 4ex;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>XYZ.com</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <form id="contact">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      </legend>
      <label><b>Name:</b>
        <input name="user" required>
      </label>
      <label><b>Email:</b>
        <input name="email" type="email" required>
      </label>
      <label><b class="top">Message:</b>
        <textarea name="message" required></textarea>
        </label>
        <!-- 
          A plain <button> needs to be within the <form> or have
          the [form] attribute with the <form>'s ID as the value
        -->
      <button>Send</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>

<footer>
  <small> 2023, XYZ.com, All rights reserved.</small>
</footer>

<!-- <dialog> is display: none until it's opened -->
<dialog>
  <!-- 
    Although <output> is outside of <form> it is still 
    associated with <output> because of [form="contact"]
  -->
  <output id="modal" form="contact"></output>
</dialog>
```